# ruby array sequential with number

Tags: arrays, ruby

Tiny alternative mode to create array sequential passing one value number in ruby?

E.g.:

```
number = 5
#output: [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I know I could use 'each' by traversing x positions by storing in an auxiliary variable. But I'd like something more practical, and I know Ruby has a lot of potential for short code.

Comment: `[*1..5]`......

Comment: much more simple than my answer

Comment: You don't even need the brackets: `ary = *1..5`

Comment: Only as a variable assignment, right @Stefan? (`*1..5` => SyntaxError)

Comment: @SebastianPalma indeed, the splat converts `1..5` to an argument list via `to_a`, so `ary = *1..5` becomes `ary = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5` which in turn is equivalent to `ary = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` due to Ruby's implicit array assignment.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the explanation @Stefan ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So simple solution:

```
(1..number).to_a
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try...

```
[*1..10]
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

or...

```
num = 10
[*1..num]
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: This is an adaptation based on the comments. But this is merit for @SebastianPalma, because he had previously commented.

Answer (score 0):

While Darlan's range solution is my preferred method, you could also use an Enumerable solution, such as:

```
5.upto(10).to_a
```

Answer (score 0):

My preferred solution is:

```
Array.new(5) { |i| i + 1 }  # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

because it's easily extended to arbitrary sequences such as:

```
Array.new(5) { |i| (i + 1)**2 }  # => [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

That's what the block form of the constructor is there for.